# Обновить версию PHP проекта

Tags: php, kohana

Сайт написан на php 5.6 (Kohana), как обновить код самого сайта до php 7.1 или php 7.2? Чтобы скорость работы сайта повысилась.

Или для обновления php кода самого проекта это тоже самое, что написать код с нуля?

Comment: Нет, мигрировать однозначно легче
http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.php

Comment: Главное не влететь в изменения разрушающие обратную совместимость.